# Extracting road from image with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to extract road area from the image. I am trying to do this with below code.
I want to detect road area to avoid detection in other part of image to avoid false positives in object detection.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img_clr = cv.imread('road.jpg')

img = cv.imread('road.jpg',0)

img = cv.medianBlur(img,5)
ret,th1 = cv.threshold(img,127,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
th2 = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
            cv.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
th3 = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
titles = ['Original Image', 'Global Thresholding (v = 127)',
            'Adaptive Mean Thresholding', 'Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding']
images = [img, th1, th2, th3]

for i in range(4):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Input image

[image: input image]

Current output image:

[image: current output image]

Expected output:

[image: expected output]

Please help me to find the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: need ai solution for this kind of scenarios like RESA/LaneATT, CondLane ..

Comment: Look into the opencv standard Hough transform. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html. This can be used to detect straight lines in images.